# Unwanted join result (matching one row with the corresponding subsequent row)

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Original table:

| row | task | event_time | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t123 | 109 | f |
| 2 | t123 | 111 | s |
| 3 | t123 | 114 | f |
| 4 | t123 | 115 | s |
| 5 | t456 | 117 | s |
| 6 | t123 | 120 | f |
| 7 | t456 | 121 | f |
| 8 | t123 | 123 | s |

### Desired result:

For a given task, I want to have a column representing its starting time `time_s` and the ***corresponding*** finish time `time_f`:

| row | task | time_s | time_f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t123 | 111 | 114 |
| 2 | t123 | 115 | 120 |
| 3 | t456 | 117 | 121 |

Below is a working example, including what I tried. That is, getting rows corresponding to the 2 possible event types via two separate query results and then joining them based on the column `task` and making sure to compare the times.

```
create table events (task text,
                 event_time int,
                 event_type text);
                 
INSERT INTO events(task,event_time,event_type)
VALUES('t123',109,'f'),
('t123',111,'s'),
('t123',114,'f'),
('t123',115,'s'),
('t456',117,'s'),
('t123',120,'f'),
('t456',121,'f'),     |
('t123',123,'s');

select t1.task, time_s, time_f from (select task, event_time as time_s from events where event_type = 's') as t1 join (select task, event_time as time_f from events where event_type = 'f') as t2 on t1.task = t2.task and t1.time_s < t2.time_f
```

However, here is what I end up with:

| row | task | time_s | time_f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t123 | 111 | 114 |
| 2 | t123 | 111 | 120 |
| 3 | t123 | 115 | 120 |
| 4 | t456 | 117 | 121 |

I'm not interested in having row #2 in the result.

Should I not be using a join to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task seems very suitable to window functions:

```
select task, event_time as time_s, time_f
from (select e.*,
             min(case when event_type = 'f' then event_time end) over (partition by task order by event_time desc) as time_f
      from events e
     ) e
where event_type = 's' and time_f is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0ef25e316638a570f8260fb49919eb80) is a db<>fiddle.